# Do I need an XA Transaction? DefaultMessageListenerContainer local transaction vs XA Connection Factory

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-jms, xa

In my Spring Boot application I have a following scenario:

1. Read message from JMS queue
2. Do some things with the data.
3. Do a JDBC insert to Oracle database

If at any stage an exception occurs, I would like to be sure that the message isn't lost and is placed in the Backout Queue.

Do I need an XA transaction between XA-enabled JMS connection factory and XA-enabled Oracle db driver? Or is it sufficient to use for example *DefaultMessageListenerContainer* with *sessionTransacted* flag set to *true*?

And if the second one is the right answer, what would be a good situation to use XA transaction?

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid XA by using Spring to synchronize the two transactions and coding your app to handle the (small) possibility of a duplicate delivery (when the DB commits but the JMS rolls back due to, say, a lost connection between the DB and JMS commit). I suggest you read the excellent [Distributed transactions in Spring, with and without XA](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077963/open-source-tools/distributed-transactions-in-spring--with-and-without-xa.html) by Dave Syer from the Spring team.

If javaworld moves that link sometime in future, google `syer xa spring` and you should find it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the link!